# Flutter: Add + icon to autocomplete?

Tags: flutter

How can I add an `Icons.add` (`+`) icon to the search list in autocomplete (not in the `textField`) with Flutter?

[image: img1]

Comment: your question is vague ,mind elaborating what you want and what you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List<String> list = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20, left: 20, top: 20),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Search",
                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      width: 2.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                      color: Colors.black54,
                      width: 2.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  if (value.isNotEmpty) {
                    autoCompleteSearch(value);
                  } else {
                    if (list.length > 0 && mounted) {
                      setState(() {
                        list = [];
                      });
                    }
                  }
                },
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: list.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      leading: CircleAvatar(
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.pin_drop,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                      title: Text(list[index]),
                      onTap: () {
                        debugPrint(list[index]);
                      },
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void autoCompleteSearch(String value) async {
    List<String> myList = ["aa", "bb", "cc", "ds", "aab", "daa"];
    var result = myList.where((element) => element.contains(value));
    if (result != null && mounted) {
      setState(() {
        list = result.toList();
      });
    }
  }
}
```